# Enable/Disable a control using Dependency Property in windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want my Log in button disable till user enter at least one character in both user name and password field for windows phone. what i did define two dependency properties in a converter and check their value but all of this not working here is my converter code.

```
public class LoginEnableConverter : DependencyObject,IValueConverter
{
    public static DependencyProperty dep_username = DependencyProperty.Register("Dep_UserName", typeof(string), typeof(LoginEnableConverter), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public string Dep_UserName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(dep_username); }
        set { SetValue(dep_username, value); }
    }

    public static DependencyProperty dep_password = DependencyProperty.Register("Dep_Password", typeof(string), typeof(LoginEnableConverter), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public string Dep_Password
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(dep_password); }
        set { SetValue(dep_password, value); }
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Dep_UserName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Dep_Password);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Dep_UserName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Dep_Password);
    }
}
```

Binding Property to Converter

```
<converter:LoginEnableConverter x:Key="EnableLogin" Dep_Password="{Binding Path=DataContext.Password}" Dep_UserName="{Binding Path=DataContext.UserName}"></converter:LoginEnableConverter>
```

My XAML Code

```
<toolkit:PhoneTextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding UserName, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,50,0,0" Background="#C9F2EE"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ActionIcon="/Assets/user_ic.png" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"  Hint="Username" Name="txtUsername"   
                 BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxStyle1}">
    </toolkit:PhoneTextBox>

    <toolkit:PhoneTextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0,30,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Name="Password"  Background="#C9F2EE"  ActionIcon="/Assets/key_ic.png"  Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxStyle1}"   Hint="Password" 
                 BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Top">            
    </toolkit:PhoneTextBox>

    <Button x:Name="btnLogin" Grid.Row="3"  Margin="0,40,0,0" Content="Log in" IsEnabled="{Binding Converter={StaticResource EnableLogin}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Width="293" Foreground="White" Background="Gray" Height="81" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle3}">
    </Button>
```

Comment: Note that the user has a requirement (per discussion below) to use MVVM and is not allowed to wire to events directly.

Answer (score 0):

In your control binding for the button, you aren't actually binding to a value. The value converter code doesn't run because there is nothing prompting it to run. Instead, you would need to bind to a property value, and have that value change when a character is typed in either box, for example.

Also, looking at your dependency properties, there is no place where you are actually calling the setters. The real place where this would need to happen is in whatever object you are using to bind to the username and password fields.

In any case, this does not have the feel of a scenario where data binding is the appropriate method to achieve the end result.  What you instead need to do is bind to the `TextChanged` event on the text box, and move the enable/disable logic to your code for the event handler.  To do so, add the following attribute to each of your text boxes: `TextChanged="OnUserOrPasswordTextChange"`

Then, in the code-behind for the page,

```
private void OnUserOrPasswordTextChange(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
     btnLogin.IsEnabled = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUsername.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password.Text);
}
```

Note that I did not test, but you should get the idea of what I'm suggesting.

For more reading about data binding, please refer to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/cc278072%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) about data binding to gain an understanding of the concepts. Pay close attention to what they do in code-behind.

Comment: Hi @rmayer06 did you provide any example i can't see that it would be more helpfull for me as i am new for all of these

Comment: This is actually a bit more involved than just providing an example. I will see if I can refer you to a good article.

Comment: You know, thinking about this - your best bet is to connect to the `TextChanged` event on the text boxes and process the logic that way. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Yes i can do that but i have to implement this using binding. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the rationale behind your requirement to use binding?

Comment: Only one thing. Must follow MVVM and don't use event directly.

Comment: I'll be honest, I am a little out of my element with this one as I view the DP framework and MVVM as a little too "black magic" for my liking (I think it violates good program design). That said, what happens if you add a "two way" to your login button binding?